# \somepenalty=10000 vs. \somepenalty 10000 vs. \somepenalty10000

Tags: tex-core, lengths, dimensions, white-space

Replacing the equality symbol with a space below or omitting the symbol at all

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\interlinepenalty=10000
% or \interlinepenalty 10000 or \interlinepenalty10000
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

does not change the result: the page breaks inside paragraphs are prohibited in any case. Why the three syntax options? What's the difference?

1. Is there a situation in which only = works?
2. Is there a situation in which only the space works?
3. Is there a situation in which only the juxtaposition works?

Comment: The alternatives are all permitted and supported by TeX itself; the difference is cosmetic.  This is a design decision by TeX's creator, and I don't know that the reasoning has been stated.  What *is* important though is that the numeric (or in some similar situations dimension) value must be cleanly terminated.  In the case of a single numeric, a space is sufficient; `\relax` also suffices. and is better if a dimension is involved.  If a control sequence ("command") follows with no space, TeX will keep on, looking for something that might resolve to a numeric value.

Comment: For more info, see the TeXbook p. 276 (also p. 272 which says `\interlinepenalty` is an 〈integer parameter〉).

Comment: 〈simple assignment〉, 〈variable assignment〉, 〈integer variable〉. The 〈equals〉 used in 〈variable assignment〉 is defined on p. 275. Your assignment is a 〈variable assignment〉, which is one of the possible forms of a 〈simple assignment〉. The production rules for 〈variable assignment〉 and 〈equals〉 answer your question (except for the space skipped after `\interlinepenalty`: this happens earlier, at the tokenization stage, and is described on p. 46).

Comment: @Just_A_Man -- `%` is absolutely *not* a terminator!  An `%` simply says "end this input line right here and (for all practical purposes) attach the start of the next line to what has just been ended.  In fact, `%` is quite dangerous when it immediately follows a numeric value or dimension.  A numeric value followed by a space followed by `%` is okay (the space terminates the numeric value).  The situation is more complicated when a line ending with a dimension is terminated by a `%`, but that's a different question.

Comment: @Just_A_Man --- "1010 text", exactly.  (An extended disquisition on `%` is at [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference. The syntax for a primitive tex assignments allows an option `=` (and optional space)

Note that

```
 \interlinepenalty 10000 or \interlinepenalty10000
```

are the same for a different reason, the space after a command name is never tokenized at all it just terminates the command so these make the same tokens.

Conversely

```
\interlinepenalty= 10000
```

the space after = is tokenized but is ignored as the assignment absorbs optional equals optionally followed by a space.

Comment: Nice explication of the three options.  But you don't say *why* DEK designed TeX this way.  (Maybe, like me, you can't think of anyplace he may have answered that question.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton can't look into his head but it's easier to see with `\let` as `\let\foo=` allows you to terminate the `\foo` token without gobbling a space.

Comment: Trying to be clear: regarding the last sentence of the answer, my reading of the TeXbook pp. 269 and 275 tells me that the space token following the `=` is absorbed not because it is preceded by `=`, but because TeX reads a 〈number〉 after the `=` sign in this case, and 〈number〉 starts with 〈optional signs〉 which starts with 〈optional spaces〉 (what I really mean is that 〈equals〉 does not, in itself, absorb any space token after the `=` sign).

Comment: @frougon yes (but I chose in this answer to aim for a top level description in English rather than reference the formal grammar)

Answer (score 7):

David C. explained that there is no differences between these three alternatives because of TeX syntax rules (the optional `=`) or because of the toknizer outputs the same result in case 2 and 3. But you have asked why? The reason is: The optional `=` is used because this is more understandable by humans. In old days (when TeX was born) each byte was counted. So: the `=` was not used in the macro bodies because these token strings must be saved into the memory. But this optional `=` was used outside macro bodies. Today, there is no such memory limitations, the usage of `=` is recommended.

Your second question: is there any case when `=` cannot be used. Yes. If the syntax context is not assignment. For example `\penalty 10000`. The primitive command `\penalty` is not primitive register, so this is not assignment but this is command to do something in vertical or horizontal list. You cannot use `=` here.

My last comment: the optional `=` may have optional space around it (one space left and one right of the `=`. So, `\interlinepenalty= 10000` is also possible. And

```
\interlinepanalty       =     10000
```

is also possible, because there is no space before `=` and only one space after the `=` character because the tokenizer converts this to `\interlinepenalty= 10000`.

Comment: @Just_A_Man The big memory wasting issue related to TeX today is derived from Knuth's decision that hyphenation patterns are not possible load on demand when document is processed. Thus: there are plenty `.fmt` files generated in the TeX distribution, each of them includes all hyphenation paterns of all languages because: maybe sometimes a document will need this special language... Only LuaTeX overcomes this limitation and enables to load the hyphenation patterns on demand.

Comment: @wipet The `=` is not optional to save memory, but to reduce the number of `\expandafter` that are needed in things like `\expandafter\interlinepenalty\csname whatever\endcsname`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Better example is with `\let` primitive because your example is not so good: you can write `\interpenalty=\csname whatever\endcsname` without any `\expandafter`. Using less `\expandafters` is only a side effect. When we look at old macros (plain.tex, for example) then we see that all assignments done outside macro bodies are with `=` and all assignments used in macro bodies (where TeX must save it to its memory) are without `=`.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I overlooked it within the answers given already, one open question remained: are there cases where the `=` is required? Yes, for example if you want to do

```
\let\foo $      % fine
\let\bar =      % incomplete
\let\baz !
```

In the above `\bar` will be let to `\let` and not to an equal sign, so you would need

```
\let\bar = =
```

(with or without the spaces).
Even more tricky:  `\let` something to a "space" token (exercise for the reader).